# Calling/Getting a php variable value inside JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, audio, jplayer

I am currently learning how jplayer works. and I've encountered this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
                oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
              });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "m4a, oga"
          });
        });
  </script>
```

I was wondering how can I get the value of a variable in a php code and insert it here?specifically here.

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
                oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
              });
```

inside the `m4a:` I want to call/insert the value of a php code like $file_path.
How can I do that? since I'll be getting the filepaths from my database and store it in a php variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `echo` it right within the JavaScript, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "<?php echo $file_path_m4a; ?>",
                oga: "<?php echo $file_path_oga; ?>"
              });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "m4a, oga"
          });
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: `;` is not necessary for single php line

Comment: How about. changing the constructor? like instead if the file is not a m4a. it wouldn't use the m4a. it will use the mp3?

Comment: @diEcho I am used to always putting a `;` so I will always put it in my code. It won't affect the output will it? **Nope.**

Comment: @user962206 You can echo a PHP variable anywhere you want in it... If you want it to be mp3 then you will probably need to specify that it is an mp3 in the script and not m4a.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  m4a: "<?php echo $file_path ?>",
```

if **short tag** is enable then it would be more readable

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var $filepath = "<?=$file_path?>"; //javascript variable can be start with $
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a: $filepath+"/filename.mp4",
            oga: $filepath+"/filename.oga",
          });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4a, oga"
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many has said to just echo the values out. The important thing is as long as the file you're working in is interpreted by PHP you can do anything no matter what the file extension is. If the file ends in .php your server likely already does this but you could also add .js or .html files to the PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a: "<?php echo FILE_PATH.filename_mp4;?>",
            oga: "<?php echo FILE_PATH.filename_ogg;?>"
          });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4a, oga"
      });
    });
```